# How can I display just a part of a string with pug/jade?

Tags: pug, substr

I would like to display a number of 250 character of a text.
`p #{description} // display all the description` 
How can I do this in pug ?

I try with substr or length but it does not work.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript methods like [`substr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) can be easily used within Pug templates. You mentioned trying `substr()` but not being successful with it. Did your attempt look like this?

```
p #{description.substr(0,250)}
```

This should create a `<p>` with the first 250 characters of the `description` string, provided it exists and is a string.

Comment: Thanks ! I forgot "0," in the brackets...